# How to trigger an event on Dialog dismiss Android?

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have a custom dialog which extends the Dialog Class, I would like to bind an event to execute some code after the Dialog is closed when the user presses the BACK button of the device. How can I do that? I found a post where someone says that the .addWindowListener() should be used when working with Dialogs and other Window widgets. But the dialog class doesn't have the addWindowListener method, so I cannot use it. Is there another way without using fragments cause I shouldn't re-write the MyCustomDialog class?

This is the code:

```
public class MyCustomDialog extends Dialog {

public MyCustomDialog(Context context, int layoutResourceId) {
    super(context);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(layoutResourceId);

}
}
```

Thanks for the attention!

EDIT: i found this on the android developers site, is there a way to use it with MyCustomDialog class?

[onDismiss DialogInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html#onDismiss%28android.content.DialogInterface%29)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are extending android Dialog class you can implement a [Dismiss Listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html) in your Activity's and set it when you create the Dialog, and then in the listener implement any functionality you want depending on the button that was used to dismiss the Dialog.

Hope this will solve your problem.

**Edit** You can use `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` which will stop closing the dialog if you touch outside of the dialog.

Something like,

```
  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context)
  dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

**OR Alternatively**

Override `onTouchEvent()` of dialog and check for action type. if the action type is
'`MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE`' means, user is interacting outside the dialog region. So in this case, you can dimiss your dialog or decide what you wanted to perform.
view plainprint?

```
dialog.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)  
    {  

       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){  
            Toast.make(getApplicationContext(), "TOuched outside the dialog", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
               this.dismiss();  
       }  
       return false;  
    }
});
```

And for back press you can do `dialog.setCancelable(false);` which will prevent dialog getting cancelled from backpress event.

OR you can alternatively override `setOnKeyListener` event and put your own code into it.

**Edit**

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                finish();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: thanks but the dialog is dismissed even when the dialog is shown and the user clicks outside of it, thus the user clicks on the blank screen, so I need also to catch that event. I would like also to trigger that event. Is there a way to do that with Dismiss Listener?

Comment: Nice explanation... great job. +1 .

Comment: Great, this is what I need. As I said before I need different implementations of those methods depending in which activiry the MyCustomDialog is instantiated, so is there a way to implement those methods (I mean onBackPressed() and onTouchEvent) WHEN I have created the dialog and not in the class definition of itself?

Comment: TouchEvent can be implemented for dialog itself no issue with that, for backpress event you can set dialog.setCancelable(false); which will prevent backpress cancellation of dialog.

Comment: see my edit for backpress event handler, I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Works beautifully with the Back button, how can I add a listener to the MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE in order to perform some functionalities when the user clicks outside the dialog?

Comment: see my edit it will let you know, how exactly to go with touch listener.

Comment: I get that Dialog.OnTouchListener cannot be resolved to a type.. Why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50134/discussion-between-themohanahuja-and-user3019105)

Answer (score 1):

You need to Override **onBackPressed** inside Dialog class. Also make sure to close dialog after override OnBackPressed .

Try this

```
public class MyCustomDialog extends Dialog {

public MyCustomDialog(Context context, int layoutResourceId) {
    super(context);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(layoutResourceId);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

     dismiss();   // make sure to call dismiss to close dialog

    // put your code here
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the onBackPressed() method should be such a callback anonymous method which I call on the activity, cause the event listener should behave in a different way depending in which activity the dialog is created and what I should do when the dialog is dismissed. Is there some method like the addWindowListener() ?

Comment: i think @TheMohanAhuja's answer best suit with your requirement. so go ahead with Dismiss Listener with Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger an event if user clicked/touched outside the dialog and close it or used the back button to close then use

```
dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                //your trigger goes here
                Toast.makeText(IntroductoryActivity.this, "on cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

But if you want to trigger an event if something dismisses the dialog, like some other event then use

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                //your trigger goes here
                Toast.makeText(IntroductoryActivity.this, "on dismiss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I adopted in *Kotlin* (*Java* is similar) is insert  the below code in all the dialogs that are created.

This listener will be triggered if the user taps the outside of the dialog unless `dial.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` and also with Back option touched (at the bottom of the Android phone screen) unless `dial.setcancelable(false)`

```
val dial = Dialog(.....)
...
dial.setOnCancelListener {  // insert
 // your code               // insert 
}                           // insert
dial.show()
```

Where `dial` points to each dialog that is created on your system.

In `you code` you put garbage collection and whatever code you want.